# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/Visual

Tags: java, exception, awt

I compiled and ran my program without problem,and when i opened Netbeans after an hour,i have this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/Visual.
Any idea?
Thank you
The code which is reasponsible for the error is:

```
    private void doneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
    Menu m = new Menu(); //here is the error
    m.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The error is :

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/Menu
at test.Step3.doneActionPerformed(Step3.java:115)
at test.Step3.access$000(Step3.java:13)
at test.Step3$1.actionPerformed(Step3.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Can you run any code with the IDE, or do all throw this exception?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  When I click on run,it show me the three windows-classes at first and when i click a button to continue,it shows me this error.

Comment: Please explain further. Assume that we don't even use NetBeans, that we aren't sitting in front of your screen seeing what you're seeing. We need the important details. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So,my program ran without problems. I close netbeans and after an hour i opened again. When i ran my programm,it show me the first window.I click on button to continue and everything was ok. The same for the next window.But when i click on button 3rd window,the program closed and it show me this error.

Comment: Then you will need to show us the code involved, the full error message, and indicate which line is responsible for the exception.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 
 private void doneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dispose();
        Menu m = new Menu(); //error is here
        m.setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: You're new here, but please post code only in your question, not in a comment. Please edit your question and place that code and description at the bottom. thanks.

Comment: If you have any idea,it will be helpful for me !

Comment: Consider re-building/compiling all your project.